# Equation that computes right isosceles triangle edges based on line thickness and density

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I am currently working on a geometric voxel-based algorithm to generate infill structures for 3D printing.

I am creating a regular 2D grid with square cells and I populate each cell of the grid with a pattern. There are two known variables - the line thickness of the pattern, and the  density of the grid, which is essentially the percentage of the grid that is filled when taking into account the thickness of each line. A value of 100% density would mean that all the grid is covered (no gaps), while a value of 50% density would mean that 50% of the grid will be filled and the other 50% will be empty.

The problem I am trying to solve is to find an equation that returns the size of each cell (n) based on the density of the grid and the thickness (a) of each of the pattern lines for each of the different patterns I'm creating. The problem is relatively easy if I just fill the cell with a square, but it becomes trickier when I fill it with 2 right isosceles triangles so I'm looking for some help regarding this case. I have included a sketch below to demonstrate better what I mean.

If anything is unclear, please let me know!

[voxel-triangles-pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tclG2.jpg)

Comment: Although we have not fully understood what you want, we have already derived an expression for $\space\large{n}\space$ in terms of $\space\large{d}\space$ and $\space\large{\alpha}\space$. While deriving it, we had to assume several things. According to this formula, for ${\large{d}}=100\%$ and ${\large{\alpha}}=1$, $\space\large{n}$ has the value 3.4142135623730950488016887242097. Is there a way for you to check this value?

Comment: Sorry, I also felt it was quite difficult to explain the problem clearly when writing the question. The value you found though is correct. I managed to come up with the equation eventually and it's n = a (2 + √2) / (1 - √(1-d)). Is it similar to the one you created?

Comment: Yes, the formula I derived is exactly equal to the one you have mentioned in your comment. May I post my derivation as an answer so that other interested parties could know how to deal with a case like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Voxelcell]

Our aim is to calculate the area of the shaded part of the $n\times n$ square shown in the diagram. To do that, we need to determine the length $BM$, i.e.,
$$BM = \dfrac{FM}{\tan\left(22.5^o\right)}=\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)\alpha.$$

Now, we can calculate the length $EF$ as shown below.
$$EF=AB-\alpha-BM=n-\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)\alpha$$

Therefore, the area of the unshaded part of the square is equal to $\left( n-\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)\alpha\right)^2$.

The density $d \left(0\le d\le1\right)$ is defined as the fraction between the unshaded area and the total area of the $n\times n$ square. Please note that $d$ is expressed here as a fraction and not as a percentage.
$$d=\dfrac{\left( n-\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)\alpha\right)^2}{n^2}$$

This can be rearranged to obtain the following quadratic equation in the sidelength of the square $n$
$$d\space{\pmb{\large{n}}}^2-2\sqrt{2}\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)\alpha\space {\pmb{\large{n}}}+2\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)\alpha^2=0$$

This equation has two positive real roots.
$$n=\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)\left(1\pm\sqrt{1-d})\right)\dfrac{\sqrt{2}\alpha}{d}$$

The larger of the two roots is the only value that is practically useful. Therefore,
$$n=\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)\left(1+\sqrt{1-d})\right)\dfrac{\sqrt{2}\alpha}{d},$$
which can also be expressed as,
$$n=\left(\dfrac{2+\sqrt{2}}{1-\sqrt{1-d}}\right)\alpha.$$